# Mongoose Schema - Required Children, not Parent

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following object in my nav schema:

```
const navItem = new Schema ({
    "title": { type: string, unique: true, required: "A Title is req."},
    .............
    "badge": {
       "label": "string",
       "class": "string"
     }
    ..............
  })
```

While badge is not required, label and class are if a badge does exist.

How would I properly show this requirement for the optional badge in my mongoose schema?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easy solution ....**

```
const badgeSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    badge: {
         label: { type: string, required: true}
         class: { type: string, required: true}
     }
    ..............
  })

const navItem = new Schema ({
    "title": { type: string, unique: true, required: "A Title is req."},
    .............
    "badge": { type: badgeSchema, required: false}
    ..............
  })
```